Reference for algebras of "bounded expansion"
Let $k$ be a field. Consider the class $C_1$ of (associative unital) $k$-algebras $A$ with the following property:

There exists a $k$-linear basis $\{e_i | i \in I\}$ of $A$ with functions $\lambda$: $I \times I \to k$ and $f$: $I \times I \to I$ such that $e_i e_j = \lambda(i,j) e_{f(i,j)}$ for every pair $(i,j) \in I \times I$.

This $C_1$ seems large enough (it contains all semigroup $k$-algebras) and natural enough to have been considered a lot of times. Where can I find results about it (e.g. can one say something useful about finite-dimensional $C_1$ algebras)? Does it have an established name?
More generally, what about the classes $C_n$ ($n \ge 2$) with $e_i e_j = \sum\limits_{t=1}^{\bf n} \lambda_t(i,j) e_{f_t(i,j)}$ (i.e. the support of a product can't grow too quickly in that basis)?
